# Column name with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am working in the ML domain. I am working with 3D tensor very often, but sometime the writing is very unclear. For instance, that line `X[1:, :, -1] = X[1:, :, -1] - X[:-1, :, -1]` (numpy package) is unclear. I would like to work with name column. Can I do that with numpy? I can't work with pandas as it is limited to 2D tensor, but what about numpy?

Comment: Have a look at [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/); it has multidimensional arrays with labelled dimensions, built on top of NumPy.

Comment: How would names make that expression clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [recarray](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Recarray.html) for addressing array columns by names.